# Creating cartogram maps in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, cartography, arctoolbox, cartogram

I have followed the exact steps from http://www.gislounge.com/how-to-make-area-cartogram-maps-in-arcgis/ and downloaded from [arcscripts.esri.com](http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15638). After adding the cartogram tool into the toolbox and I try to invoke it, it says the tool (newly added cartogram tool) is **not valid**. And when I reopen the same file, the "+" icon in front of the cartogram tool will be missing as if I can't go to the specification pop-up screen. Could this be a compatibility issue (the Arcgis is 10.2.2)? If so, where can I find the right tool to add?

Comment: Can you include the exact steps that you used in your question body, please?  It looks like no potential answerers have been prepared to follow the link you provided and then try to synthesize your question.